Sending image created from canvas as binary data
I have image data and I want to send this to API as binary.
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("data",{"test":1});
//make jpg image from canvas.        
var image = ref_canvas_release.current.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.85);

//////// confirm and test the image file is correctly created. it created and downloaded successfully.
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = image;
a.download = 'test.jpg';
a.click();
////////

formData.append("file",image);

axios.post("/myuploader",formData,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/form-data'}}).then(res=>{
    console.log(res)
});

In this case, payload (on googld chrome developper console) shows like this,

The file is sent like this below.
file: data:image/jpeg;base64, /9j/.....

However I want to send the data as binary,
(if so payload screen is supposed to be)
file: binary

How can I change the format to send the API?

It’s multipart/form-data, not application/form-data.
